# check if value is numeric and greater than 0

Tags: c#

I have value 0.075445054945055 for a variable corrected count and have the following function. Basically I need a function which would see if the value is a numeric and greater than 0. My current function only works for integers and not for values like 0.075 etc.

The field correctedCount comes from a file when its parsed.

```
  var correctedCount
  int num;
  bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(correctedCount, out num);

  if (isNumeric)
   {

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could treat it as a double like so:

```
double num;
if (double.TryParse(correctedCount, out num))
{
    // it's at least a number, now verify it's > 0
    return num > 0;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Edit: this works because numbers without decimal parts (e.g., "4") are still valid doubles, as well as "0.075"

Comment: but the value could very well be an integer as well as a decimal

Answer (score 8):

You can use `decimal.TryParse` or `double.TryParse`